# getting an "undefined error in my react application and can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm working on a movie database application in React and am working on the functionality for adding movies to a watchlist and a favorites list. When I click on the button to add to favorites there's no problem, but When I click on the button to add to watchlist, the app crashes and I get the following error.

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
        at Movie (Movie.js:21:1)
        at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
        at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
        at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
        at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
        at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
        at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

here's the code

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Popular from '../components/Popular';
    
    const IMG_API = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300";
    
    const Movie = ({
        faves,
        setFaves,
        watchlist,
        setwatchlist,
        id,
        poster,
        title,
        date,
        media_type,
        vote_average,
        overview
    }) => {
    
        const isInWatchlist = watchlist.find(movie => movie.id === id);
        const isInFaves = faves.find(movie => movie.id === id);
    
    
        return (
            <div className='card'>
                <img src={IMG_API + poster} alt={title} />
                {/* <p>{title}</p> */}
                <div className="saveContent">
                    <p>{overview}</p>
                    <div className='watchlist-wrapper'>
    
                        <p>{isInFaves ? "Remove from" : "Add to"} favorites</p>
                        <button onClick={() => {
                            if (isInFaves) {
                                console.log('im in faves!')
                                const newFaves = faves.filter(movie => movie.id !== id);
                                setFaves(newFaves)
                            } else {
                                setFaves([{ id, poster_path: poster, title, date, 
         media_type, vote_average }, ...faves])
                            }
    
    
                        }}>{isInFaves ? " - " : "+"}</button>
    
    
                        <p>{isInWatchlist ? "Remove from" : "Add to"} watch-list</p>
                        <button onClick={() => {
                            if (isInWatchlist) {
                                const newWatchList = watchlist.filter(movie => movie.id 
    !== id);
    
                                setwatchlist(newWatchList)
                            } else {
    
    
                                setwatchlist([{ id, poster_path: poster, title, date, 
        media_type, vote_average }, ...watchlist])
                                console.log(poster)
                            }
                        }}>{isInWatchlist ? " - " : "+"}</button>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
                {/* <p>{date}</p> */}
            </div>
                )
            }
    
    export default Movie
```

it appears as though the problem is with the faves.find function, which is confusing to me because that function isn't supposed to be called when I click the watchlist button. When I click "add to favorites" however, the faves.find function works perfectly. If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Put a debug point or log before these lines const isInWatchlist = watchlist.find(movie => movie.id === id);
        const isInFaves = faves.find(movie => movie.id === id);. And check the values of faves and watchlist... Seems one of these two variables is undefined

Comment: Seems pretty simply... `faves` or `watchlist` ( which ever is on line 21) is `undefined`. Since they're both props, check the values you're passing in to your component... `<Movie watchlist={check_this_value} faves={and_this_one} ...`. I'd also strongly recommend you start using Typescript so you avoid making these mistakes

Answer (score 0):

On line 21 you're trying to call the function/method `find()` on the prop `faves` and assign the result to the variable `isInFaves`.

```js
const isInFaves = faves.find(movie => movie.id === id);
```

The error is saying the prop `faves` you passed to `Movie` in that instance does not contain the method `find()`.

Somewhere up your component tree the `Movie` component is being used, but the `faves` prop has not been passed to it, or the `faves` prop is being passed, but doesn't contain the method `find()`.

Check all the places you're using the `Movie` component and make sure the `faves` prop that has the method `find()` is being passed to the `Movie` component.